# GeoServer WPS source code

Tags: geoserver, java, wps

Is it possible to get source codes of all implemented wps processes? 
I want to create one big chained process in Java instead of using WPS builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the GeoServer source at https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver

Some community contributions are in https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/tree/master/src/community

You will be able to find the free and open-source plugins in there.

Answer (score 4):

[GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) is using [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) (and [JTS](https://github.com/locationtech/jts)) under the hood to provide those processes, there are 3 key modules all under [unsupported](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/master/modules/unsupported):

1. [Vector Processes](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/master/modules/unsupported/process-feature/src/main/java/org/geotools/process/vector)
2. [Geometry Processes](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/master/modules/unsupported/process-geometry/src/main/java/org/geotools/process/geometry)
3. [Raster Processes](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/master/modules/unsupported/process-raster/src/main/java/org/geotools)