# Java - GeoServer WPS - how to return TIFF file?

Tags: geoserver, java, wps

I'd like to return a TIFF created with a Java WPS process (this part works fine) but GeoServer seems don't recognize byte[] or File  response type as I expected.

If I return a base64 encoded string, the TIFF seems not correct (and maybe some Geo info missings ?).

Anyway, I can save my TIFF in a public server directory (e.g Apache) or create new TIFF with GeoServer REST API, but I think it's more efficient to directly return the TIFF file in WPS response to just show an OpenLayers result without saving.

Is it possible and if not, what type (mimeType) are allow by GeoServer?

Answer (score 1):

Catched.

To return a TIFF from WPS response, JAVA methods juste have to return the calculated GridCoverage :

```
return (GridCoverage2D) PROCESSOR.doOperation(param);
```

Geoserver detect TIFF file and allow to download it :

[image]

Thanks to this post (help identify GeoServer WPS source code) :

[GeoServer WPS source code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229410/geoserver-wps-source-code)